# Excel - count items from a certain weekday within a certain time period

Tags: excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet where entries are listed with a date and time, like so:
[image: Excel spreadsheet, dates in column A and times in column B]

I need it to count all entries from the combination of certain weekdays and time periods, e.g.

```
Monday, 11am - 12pm
Monday, 12pm - 1pm
Monday, 1pm - 2pm
Tuesday, 11am - 12pm
```

and so on.

I can count just what happens on certain weekdays with `=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(Data!A2:A500)=2))` etc and what happens in certain time periods with `=COUNTIF(Data!B2:B500,">=11:00:00 AM")-COUNTIF(Data!B2:B500, ">=12:00:00 PM")` etc but I can't figure out how to successfully combine the formulae.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use following formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT((WEEKDAY(Data!A2:A15)=E2)*(Data!B2:B15>=F2)*(Data!B2:B15<=G2))
```

Change range as per your data. See image for reference.

[image]

I've used `Column D` just to show corresponding `WEEKDAY`.